# Toggle show/hide div with modulo for multiple different items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a long list of items/posts much like Facebook. Each item/post has its own set of buttons that can be toggled.

```
var commentToggle = 0;

$(".comment-icon").click(function(){

    commentToggle++;

    if (commentToggle % 2 === 0) {
      $(this).closest(".item").find(".comments").fadeOut(); // close comment box
      return; 
    }

    $(this).closest(".item").find(".comments").fadeIn(); // show comment box
    $(this).find("path").attr("fill","#3684FF");
    $(this).parents().siblings(".number-of").css("color","#3684FF");

});
```

However, I have a problem that if you click the comments icon on a post, then scroll down to another post and click that one's comment icon, since the number is now even it won't open it unless you click once again.

Is there any way to solve that?

**EDIT:** The comments section is hidden at first for all posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something along the lines of:

**Updated**

```
$(function(){

  $(".comment-icon").click(function(){

    $(this).closest(".item").find(".ripple").show();


    if ($('.comments').is(":visible")) {
      $(this).closest(".item").find(".comments").fadeOut();
      $(".ripple").fadeOut();
      return;
    } else {
         $(this).closest(".item").find(".comments").fadeIn();
        $(this).find("path").attr("fill","#3684FF");
        $(this).parents().siblings(".number-of").css("color","#3684FF");
    }



  });
});
```

Then it would reset for every time the user wants to click the button, only after it's executed the if statement.

**Edit**

I made it so that it checks if the element is visible, which is basically what fadeIn() and fadeOut() control, tell me how it goes!

Comment: That closes it on first click?

Comment: Could you please post a fiddle. Allow me to understand, so you have an icon that when clicked, it opens, then it closes, but if you want to open 2 comment sections without closing the previous one, it won't unless you click the icon twice?

Comment: Well when you attempt to click an icon on first go, yours just closes it since `commentToggle === 1` due to the `commentToggle++` before it. Therefore it will run the `if block` on first click and never open it.

Comment: Could you please make a fiddle so i can play around with the code, would be much easier. Also, the comment section is closed at first, correct?

Comment: I can try to make a fiddle, it might take me a while though. Yes sorry, it's hidden at first (forgot to mention that). You click the comment icon to open it, then again to re-close it.

Comment: Please check my edit, I think it should work, good luck :) If it doesn't I'll just wait for your fiddle!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xLxa8r5x/ - extremely crude, but just click the comments icon to see what i mean

Comment: That works nicely but `$(this).closest(".item").find(".comments").is(":visible")` with that. Didn't know about `.is(":visible")`! It created some other unrelated problems but I think I can fix them.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xLxa8r5x/1/ I think this would work with any comments, hope this is what you wanted!

Comment: Yeah just change `if ($('.comments').is(":visible"))` to `if($(this).closest(".item").find(".comments").is(":visible"))` and it's fine! Thanks.

Comment: Oh okay! Glad I could help! :)